# Having Issues with data not plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I currently have a database in sqlite3 that is roughly 750 lines of wage/iq data. I am trying to visualize this on a surface plot using matplotlib however with my current code I am getting nothing on my plot. There are no errors printing which leads me to believe I must be missing some variable somewhere.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sqlite3



conn = sqlite3.connect('wages2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT mother_edu, log_wage_1980, tenure_1980, reference, iq FROM WageIQ')
rows = dict()
mother = list()
iq = list()
wages = list()
tenure = list()
count = 0
for medu in cur:
    count = count +1
    rows[count] = (medu[0],medu[1],medu[2],medu[3],medu[4])
    mother.append(medu[0])
    iq.append(medu[4])
    wages.append(medu[1])
    tenure.append(medu[2])

mother_edu = np.array([mother])
iq_a = np.array([iq])
wages_a = np.array([wages])

print(mother_edu)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

x, y, z, = mother_edu, iq_a, wages_a
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

[plot photo][1]
[snip of data printout][2]
```

[plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IENLW.png)
[numpy array output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn7OC.png)

```
AMENDED CODE BELOW...

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('wages2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT mother_edu, log_wage_1980, tenure_1980, reference, iq 
FROM WageIQ')
rows = dict()
mother = list()
iq = list()
wages = list()
tenure = list()
count = 0
for medu in cur:

    count = count +1
    rows[count] = (medu[0],medu[1],medu[2],medu[3],medu[4])
    mother.append(medu[0])
    iq.append(medu[4])
    wages.append(medu[1])
    tenure.append(medu[2])

mother_edu = np.array(mother)
iq_a = np.array(iq)
wages_a = np.array(wages)
tenure_a = np.array(tenure)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(mother_edu.min(), mother_edu.max()),
    np.arange(iq_a.min(), iq_a.max())
    )

Z = np.empty(X.shape)

for x,y,z in zip(mother_edu, iq_a, tenure):
    Z[np.where((X == x) & (Y == y))] = z
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.set_zlim()
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(1))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect =5)

plt.show()
```

[colorbar surface plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6PCn.png)

Comment: A surface plot requires X,Y,Z to be 2D arrays. From your code it seems that you are using a 1D array. One solution could be to use a scatter plot, the other is to properly formt your arrays. Eg  X=[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]  Y = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]] and Z as the array of correspending values for your XY grid, [np.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is a usefull tool to generate XY grids for a surface plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment (The problem is that you are forcing your data into a 2D array but you are not using a proper XY grid needed for a surface plot), here is an example of how you could manipulate your data to make a surface plot.
(Of course I am using random number, while you should use your own data)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Generate random data, here you just use the data from your database
mother = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(80))
iq = np.random.randint(60,250, size=(80))
wages = np.random.randint(500,2000, size=(80))

mother_edu = np.array(mother)
iq_a = np.array(iq)
wages_a = np.array(wages)

# Generate a X,Y meshgrid, sampling the XY space in steps of 1
X,Y = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(mother_edu.min(), mother_edu.max()),
    np.arange(iq_a.min(), iq_a.max())
    )

# Create a 2D Z array from the 1d one
# eg: x = [x0, ....]  y = [y0, ...] z = [z0, ...]
#     X = [[..., x0, ...], ..., [..., x0, ...]]
#     Y = [[...], ..., [y0 , y0, y0, ...], ..., [...]]
#     Z = [[...], ..., [..., z0, ...], ..., [...]]
Z = np.empty(X.shape)
for x,y,z in zip(mother_edu, iq_a, wages_a):
    Z[np.where((X == x) & (Y == y))] = z


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

Here how the output would look like
[image: Output]

How YOUR code should look like

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sqlite3



conn = sqlite3.connect('wages2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT mother_edu, log_wage_1980, tenure_1980, reference, iq FROM WageIQ')
rows = dict()
mother = list()
iq = list()
wages = list()
tenure = list()
count = 0
for medu in cur:
    count = count +1
    rows[count] = (medu[0],medu[1],medu[2],medu[3],medu[4])
    mother.append(medu[0])
    iq.append(medu[4])
    wages.append(medu[1])
    tenure.append(medu[2])

mother_edu = np.array(mother)
iq_a = np.array(iq)
wages_a = np.array(wages)

# Generate a X,Y meshgrid, sampling the XY space in steps of 1
X,Y = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(mother_edu.min(), mother_edu.max()),
    np.arange(iq_a.min(), iq_a.max())
    )

# Create a 2D Z array from the 1d one
# eg: x = [x0, ....]  y = [y0, ...] z = [z0, ...]
#     X = [[..., x0, ...], ..., [..., x0, ...]]
#     Y = [[...], ..., [y0 , y0, y0, ...], ..., [...]]
#     Z = [[...], ..., [..., z0, ...], ..., [...]]
Z = np.empty(X.shape)
for x,y,z in zip(mother_edu, iq_a, wages_a):
    Z[np.where((X == x) & (Y == y))] = z


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Just so I can better understand the example, when you say use my own data are you referring to the list from the loop, or the columns themselves from the sqlite file? Also could you please explain how the meshgrid tool works as well as the for loop you added? Apologies for my painful slowness on this, I would just like to truly understand the method.

Comment: @CamWilliams For "use your own data" I mean use the data you want to plot. Since i don't have your database i just used random numbers. Regarding [np.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) I would refer you to the documentation as linked. In brief it generate a 2D XY grid starting from 2 1D arrays (eg: X,Y = np.meshgrid([0,1,2], [0,1,2]) -> X = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]  Y = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]) It is kindof tasselate the XY plane. The second loop is used to assign the corresponding value of Z to every point of the grid

Comment: You have been exceptionally helpful! I'm not sure of an easy way to show you my sqlite file but I will try to fiddle around with it. I think what I am having a hard time with at this point is the "mother = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(80))" portion. would the min/max sections of the code the min/max of the column being referenced? I had tried min(mother),max(mother) but am unsure of the size parameter.

Comment: @CamWilliams That line is where I am generating the random data. You just don't put it in your code and use the array that you have in your code snippet (All the line where you extract the data from your database, from 'conn = sqlite3.connect('wages2.sqlite')' to 'tenure.append(medu[2])'.
The min/max part is to generate a grid that encompass all your data. You can replace it with fixed values if you want to plot only a portion

Comment: If I am understanding your direction does that mean that the np.random/randint portion should not be there if I am using my dataset? If I remove that I get a "ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (758,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (0,18)" error. Where might I find documentation on this so that I could format my variables correctly?

Comment: I added how your code should look like. You jsut had to replace the 3 np.random line with your for loop

Comment: I appreciate your patience and thoroughness in explaining this to me! It is a bit of a chaotic dataset for a surface map which I am seeing now but the proof of concept is very strong. I have amended my original post showing the code and the output. Thank you again!

Comment: @CamWilliams Your welcome. Since this helped you, please accept the answer ;)